# Apache RewriteRule include whatever after the string

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule inside my website's root .htaccess which suppose to prevent people from downloading zip files from my site unless they are on it. it goes like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?example.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(doc|zip|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(doc|zip|pdf)$ http://example.com/ [nc]
```

The thing is, when you type a url which includes the zip file and then add any character afterwards (examples below), it sends you to the webhost 404 page instead of my own Wordpress 404 / example.com

```
http://example.com/some.zip/
http://example.com/some.zip/123
http://example.com/some.zip/asd
```

can someone please advise me how to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$` anchor after `.zip`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?example.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(doc|zip|pdf)(/|$) http://example.com/ [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks! :) this works flawlessly, and to think I could simply ask that here, instead of hours of googling and trying so many different things, shishh..